# Filter and sort results, ignoring rows with no data, with 2, 3 or 4 conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large database from Y to BF.

Columns Y to AB are the categories of all the rest.

I want to apply a filter function that will only filter results with rows with data (ignore all other columns/rows blank).

Conditions for Filter are in B2 ; D2 ; F2 ; H2 .

I also want to be able to Sort results according to O2 and in a Ascending or Descending order according to Q2.

In A6 I have a formula that only shows titles with corresponding data, BUT it doesn't respect possible 4 conditions, only one, the first in B2

```
=FILTER( AD2:AJ2,INDEX(AD2:AJ,MATCH( B2,Y3:Y,0 ),)<>"" )
```

In A7 i have a formula (not working) that only fills filtered results according with B2 + D2 + F2 + H2 BUT doesn't show only rows with data, it shows all columns

```
=IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(AD3:BF,
IF(B2="",ROW(Y3:Y),Y3:Y=B2)*
IF(D2="",ROW(Z3:Z),Z3:Z=D2)*
IF(F2="",ROW(AA3:AA),AA3:AA=F2)*
IF(H2="",ROW(AB3:AB),AB3:AB=H2)),
IF(O2="",1,MATCH(O2,A6:R6,0)),
IF(Q2="Asc",1,0)),"Sem Navios")
```

My difficulty is that my current formulas respect the 4 conditions (even in case some one is blank) BUT does not filter columns only with data, it spills all columns and that is very confusing.

Can someone help me getting to filter data according to 4 conditions (even in case some one is blank), being able to sort and only shows rows with data?

Thanks.

Example sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11B-4rjP9_8brvF0A3yVJlIoiyXWqxM91qWtKRSD8tLI/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to edit.

I have a "desired results" tab, with no formulas, just showing what I pretend.

Comment: as your previous question this one also needs to be done with QUERY

Comment: Have you tried using `QUERY` formula?

Comment: I don´t understand that well QUERY function, i have seen some videos, seems a powerful function, but i dont know how to use it for this purpose...